# Definir post_type search widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como definir o parâmetro `post_type` para o widget de busca do Wordpress. O widget é exibido no cabeçalho da página.

Atualmente estou usando o seguinte código:

```
echo the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Search');
```

O widget é exibido corretamente, só preciso definir o parâmetro `post_type`. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi da [documentação de `the_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget), seria algo como `the_widget('WP_Widget_Search', 'post_type=post');`, ou talvez `the_widget('WP_Widget_Search', '', 'post_type=post')`. Imagino que os valores possíveis para `post_type` sejam os descritos na [documentação de Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não encontrei pista nem maneira de fazer como [sugeriu Dang nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17205/definir-post-type-search-widget#comment32429_17205). Pensei também em filtrar os resultados da busca usando o hook `posts_where`, mas não tenho nem idéia de como reconhecer se a busca está sendo feita por nosso widget ou por outro formulário de busca.

Encontrei [uma maneira bastante simples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67156/12615) de filtrar os resultados que é colocando um campo de entrada do tipo:

```
<input type="hidden" value="portfolio" name="post_type" />
```

[Estudando o `WP_Widget_Search`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L219) vejo que não há nenhuma maneira de modificá-lo para incluir o filtro, então a solução é fazer uma cópia do widget e adaptá-la. A modificação que fiz foi remover o `get_search_form()` e puxar/modificar [o código dessa mesma função](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L182).

*PS: adapte o CPT para sua necessidade, aqui está sendo usado `portfolio`.*

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Widget Search by CPT
 * Plugin URI: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17233/201
 * Author: brasofilo
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'b5f_sopt_search' );

function b5f_sopt_search() {
    register_widget( 'B5F_SOPT_Search_Widget' );
}

class B5F_SOPT_Search_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_search', 'description' => __( "A search form for your site.") );
        parent::__construct( 'search', _x( 'Search', 'Search widget' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        $format = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'search-form' ) ? 'html5' : 'xhtml';
        if ( 'html5' == $format ) {
            $form = '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" title="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '" />
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" value="portfolio" name="post_type" />
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="'. esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) .'" />
            </form>';
        } else {
            $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</label>
                    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="portfolio" name="post_type" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) .'" />
                </div>
            </form>';
        }
        echo $form;
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '') );
        $title = $instance['title'];
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></label></p>
<?php
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $new_instance = wp_parse_args((array) $new_instance, array( 'title' => ''));
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Finalmente, modifique seu código para:

```
echo the_widget( 'B5F_SOPT_Search_Widget' );
```

<sub>*Relacionado:* [**Can't limit search to only pages**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50828/12615)</sub>
<sub>*Importante:* [**Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)</sub>